# Outlook rules with both pop and exchange accounts on multiple computers don't work

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules, microsoft-outlook-365

Have an issue with Outlook rules when I have both an exchange account and pop account on the same computer. The exchange rules work fine all the time, this is about pop rules. Exchange automatically syncs all rules including ones only used for non-exchange accounts and pst files, and I have to use the "this computer only" option to get pop rules to function. If I do not check that option, the rules simply don't work, everything goes to the inbox.

[image]

*The "client-only" rules work, the ones without this option do not work for a pop account when an exchange account is also being used.*

This breaks the ability to use rules on a second or third computer entirely when exchange is used on both of them because when the pop rules with "this computer only" sync, they show up as "For other computer" on additional computers which also do not function.

[image]

Is there any way to get local pop rules to work on multiple computers when an exchange account is also on that computer? This seems like such a basic function, I have to be missing something.

Comment: Give Outlook POP and Outlook Exchange different Outlook Profiles. Only once instance can run at once time and that should solve your issue.

Comment: That's not going to work, I need to have both running at the same time.

Comment: May be, but that is where your problem lies.

Comment: Understood, appreciate the responses

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research and here's a blog on [configure separate rules for Exchange and POP3 accounts](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/777) for your reference.

You could follow this step by step guidance and check if your issue could be resolved.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The specified account dropdown looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: Actually, adding the second computer breaks it, have to duplicate the rules so each computer has local ones, or it reverts to "for other computer" for everything. But even then it's really buggy, have been testing for a few hours and it removes the "specified account" settings on rules almost at random.